# Why and When close a consumer?

Tags: apache-kafka, rabbitmq, apache-kafka-streams

I understand it's about leaking resources. But I believe the concept here is a consuming service can't know when a producer will produce a message. So I understand, generally, it should not be closed and even if there is the some issue with processing the message, it can be handled without bringing down the consumer. So what exactly would be the use case wherein one would need to close a consumer?

Answer (score 0):

Although it is true that consumers are usually long-running applications that continuously poll data from a Kafka cluster, it is more than likely that the application that you are considering to develop it's going to end at some point.

By the time your application ends if you've failed to close your consumer the Kafka Broker has to recognize that the consumer has left the consumer group, which takes time and failed messages. To do this the broker uses: *session.timeout.ms* controls which determine how long a consumer can go without sending a heartbeat.

While this won't make much of a difference if you are using a single application with a couple of consumers, it can affect harshly (efficiency-wise) to your Kafka cluster if you are using multiple consumers for the same topic, causing many rebalances which can slow (or stop) your processing time.

That's why you should always close your consumer before exiting an application or a process (even if in your application you use an infinite loop to consume your data).

```
try {
    while (true) { 
        /*Code with consuming process*/
        }
    }
} finally {
    consumer.close(); 
}
```

Here is the [Kafka Guide](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/kafka-the-definitive/9781491936153/ch04.html) on this topic for more information.